# VBA Excel, Infinite Loop unable to open excel and edit VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I accidentally run my VBA excel in an infinite loop.

Excel hang and then it closed.
Now everytime I try to open my Excel file, it ask if I want to Run in Safe Mode.
When I click Yes, it shows my Excel for a while, the close again. My mouse shows loading icon during that few short seconds and I can't do anything.
I can't go to VBA to edit my code.

Is it because the VBA code is still running at the background? If so, how to I stop it?
I even restarted my PC and I still can't open my Excel file to edit the code cuz excel will keep crashing.

The loop is a FIND of a certain word.
Is there anyway to restore my code without needing to open Excel, then Developer Tools > VBA?

Please assist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep down the SHIFT-key when opening the file. This will prevent the Workbook_Open code from running. Hope it helps.

Comment: What version did you test that on? I've seen that method posted, but not been able to get it to work with 64=bit `365` with a new `xlsm` file. Haven't tested on other versions.

Answer (score 0):

*This is for `365`; not sure about earlier versions:*

To prevent your VBA code from running when you open Excel:

- Open Excel with a new, blank workbook
- Navigate `File => Options => Trust Center => Trust Center Settings`

[image]

- Macro Settings => Disable VBA Macros with notification

[image]

Now you should be able to open your file without any of your VBA macros running.

Be sure to reset this to your desired settings after you have figured out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to start Excel, open the VBA editor and enter `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the immediate window and press enter.

Remember to change it back to `Application.EnableEvents = True` after your troubleshooting is finished.